Strange shading errors for seemingly normal topology in cycles
This model seems to have normal topology (all quads and there are no n-gons) My first thought would be the very narrow quad at the front of the boat, but making the front wider didn't do anything. I am shading smooth but it looks even worse shaded flat.




Could you try and clear Custom Split Normals ? Otherwise, could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ ?

thanks but none of those worked. I added the blender files to the question. Also thank you gordon for fixing the image.

Smoother shading with a few tweaks

I was able to get better shading on your boat model with the following changes.
Join the boat to a plane, then go into edit mode and delete the plane mesh. This resets the transforms and gets rid of any strange object data that may be hanging around. Sometimes this helps when clearing Custom Split Normals fails to improve shading.
Delete the existing material and create a new one. The shading got a lot smoother when I switched to a Principled Shader instead of a Toon Shader. If you still want a toon look, look up tutorials on NPR shader setups.
Use smooth shading with Autosmooth checked. This automatically splits the mesh on the sharp edges, giving you smooth shading on the side of the boat but keeping the hard creases defining the top and bottom.

Add edge loops around the sides of your the boat. Shading is better when quads are closer to square.
Add environment and lighting. Most of your shading problems should be solved now, but it's very difficult for single Point Light to flatter your model. Try using a Sun Lamp or Environment Texture and a ground plane to get some more life into the shading of your model.
Water

World

UPDATE I realized in these tweaks i forgot to check face orientation. I believe your boat surface has backfaces pointed out. use Shift-N to recalculate the normals.

I tried everything and basic google search finally helped me, the issues are:
Long quads that 'break' at an angle turn into triangles causing this shading, if you triangulate the mesh manually and change the Quad Method to Longest Diagonal or Fixed Alternate you can see these triangles change direction.
The problem is that everything is converted to quads, this is only seen with 'broken' quads.
Related and answered: Fix triangular lighting artifacts
